# Library for extracting hash arguments in ruby

Tags: ruby

Sometimes it is nice to use hash as methods arguments:

```
foo(:bar => 'baz', :foo => 123)
```

There is any library which helps parsing such signature ie. sets validation or default values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shameless punt:

https://rubygems.org/gems/magic_options

Answer (score 3):

try https://github.com/intridea/hashie

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding an example showing how this gem improves the handling of hash arguments.